# Why is desktop taking too long to come up?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, ati

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my machine with gnome shell  3.4.1 installed.

Recently,  I have installed AMD Radeon graphics driver from the AMD website in my ubuntu. After that I have noticed that after I type my password correctly on the login screen, desktop takes too long to come up.
A black screen with a mouse pointer on it shows up for about 5-19 seconds before desktop shows up.

Can anyone point out the possible solutions or the possible causes of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both GNOME SHell and Unity 3D Shell are highly resource intensive. even my laptop has an AMD graphics hardware and I experience the same lag as you do even in gnome-classic session(although that is just for about 3-5 seconds at max because gnome-classic is very light on resources).

Your problem might be because the drivers form the AMD website are not updated and fixed regularly. Using those drivers will help you to run the graphics hardware on your laptop, but they will cause some bugs and quirks on your system. Like the one you posted.

Why don't you try the open-source drivers developed by the community by removing your previous drivers(just do a google search and you get how to do that in Ubuntu) and then installing the fglrx-updates from the software center? They *might* work for you. (Although I am personally quite satisfied with the drivers form the AMD website. They do have a few quirks but work fine for me almost all the time.